# Android app that takes a picture every X second

Tags: android, photography

I am looking for an Android app that will take a picture every set number of seconds.

The way I'd like to use the app is as follow:

> When I'll be going on a family trip to a remote city by car, I'd like to install my Android phone on a phone holder, start the app, configure the number of seconds (e.g. every 1 second) and hit the "start" button. Then the app would take a picture of whatever is in front of it (and in front of the car) every second and save it somewhere on the device. When I get to my destination, I hit the "stop" button and the app stops taking pictures.
>
> Then, when I get the chance to plug my phone to my laptop, I unload the images and possibly make a movie of the ride to the remote city.

The features that are *required*:

- Android 4+ (phone or tablet)
- Time allowed between snapshots must be at least between 1 second and one month (could be more than one month, and/or less than one second)
- No limit to the number of pictures taken (other than the device memory)
- 1920x1080 resolution must absolutely be available as a picture size (or a better 16:9 resolution)
- No or low image compression, I need good image quality
- A way to evaluate the app without having to pay
- On/off button or equivalent; I don't want to have to *hold* the 'take picture' button

The features that are *good to have*:

- Free
- I'd like the screen to stay on the whole time so I know it's working
- Insertion of the latitude/longitude information into the picture meta data (I think it's possible by just taking normal pictures on a phone)
- Possibility to decide where to save the images on the device

Comment: Your requirements puzzle me... You want to be able to set it to one month time between snapshots and you also want the screen to stay on the whole time! I am puzzled where that would be useful...

Answer (score 2):

For an easy solution, checkout [Microsoft Hyperlapse Mobile](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.hyperlapsemobile)

This app creates a hyper lapse (movie) for you, without you having to pull the pictures off of your phone and upload them and create a video, etc.

When you open the app, you can either take a new hyper lapse, or import an existing video that you want to convert to a hyper lapse.
After you have imported or recorded a video, you can choose what speed to export it (2x, 4x, 8x, 16x, or 32x)
Hyperlapse also does impressive stabilization, so the end result is a smooth video.

Here is an [example video](https://youtu.be/gdFDOO3Gnlw) I put together of what it can do

Answer (score 0):

**[Framelapse Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.neximolabs.droidtimelapsepro)** meets almost all of your requirements (currently $2.99)

- Android 4+ (phone or tablet)
- Time allowed between snapshots must be at least between 1 second and one month *(Framelapse Pro allows from 0.1 seconds up to 24 hours)*
- No limit to the number of pictures taken (other than the device memory)
- 1920x1080 resolution must absolutely be available as a picture size (or a better 16:9 resolution)
- No or low image compression, I need good image quality
- On/off button or equivalent; I don't want to have to *hold* the 'take picture' button

**Other Features:**

- Custom self timer to delay recording start: This is helpful to prevent camera shake from starting the recording.
- Front and back camera support
- Zoom and autofocus options
- White balance control: 
  (*auto, incandescent, fluorescent, warm-fluorescent, daylight, cloudy-daylight, twilight, shade*) as well as White Balance Lock
- Exposure compensation:
  (*+2 EV, +1 EV, +0 EV, -1EV, -2EV*) as well as Exposure Lock
- Color filter effects: (*none, mono, negative, solarize, sepia, posterize, aqua*)
- Custom bit rate
- Displays length of time-lapse video being recorded
- Custom storage directory to store the video if your device supports it
- Change video frame rate (default, 24fps, 25fps, 30fps)
- Displays length of time-lapse video being recorded
- Set video duration to automatically stop recording (or infinity)

I have used this app and it has done very well for me. Here is an [example video](https://youtu.be/lqfie5THwbg) I put together.